# Syntax error reported in basic C code - what is wrong?

Tags: c

The code is given below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   //FILE *fps;
   char secret[512] =" ";
   FILE *fps = fopen("/etc/comp2700/share/secret", "r");

   if(fps == NULL)
   {
       printf("Secret file not found\n");
       return 1;
   }

   fgets(secret, 512, fps);
   printf("Secret: %s\n", secret);
   fclose(fps);

   return 0;   
}
```

When I am trying to run this program it is repeatedly throwing the following error:

```
./attack1.c: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./attack1.c: line 4: `int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )'
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem here. Copied, pasted, and compiled your code with no errors.

Comment: I am using this in Ubuntu.Does that make a difference

Comment: No it shouldn't.  Did you forget to compile your code? `gcc -o attack1 attack1.c`

Comment: I tried on centos (`gcc`) and it works fine.

Comment: As @NiallCosgrove says: don't try to run the c file itself (even after making it executable). That's not how C works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile your source file with gcc as follows

`gcc -o attack attack1.c`

then run it with

`./attack`

You should read up on the difference between *compiled* versus *interpreted* languages.

There is a short video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNMy969SjyU) explaining the difference.

Comment: Better add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion` when compiling.

Comment: @alk didn't want to bombard an obvious beginner with too much information. Those flags will produce two warnings for the unused params argc,argv. Those warnings are not relevant to his core issue.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run your C program from the command line as `./attack1.c`. Normally the shell would refuse to execute the C source file because it should not have execute permission, but for some reason, on your system, it must have the `x` bits and is read by the default shell as a script.

Of course this fails because `attack1.c` contains C code, not a command file. Note that the `#include` lines are interpreted as comments by the shell and the error only occurs at line 4.

To run a C program, you must first compile it to produce an executable:

```
gcc -Wall -o attack1 attack1.c
```

And then run the executable if there were no compilation errors:

```
./attack1
```

You can combine these commands as

```
gcc -Wall -o attack1 attack1.c && ./attack1
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to compile the `attack.c` code using the following command:

```
gcc attack.c
```

This will create one executable file `a.out` which you can run using the following command:

```
./a.out
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Not my downvote, but what does this add to the other answer, which preceded this one by hours?

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger. It's the same thing just that we are not specifying the executable file name. I believe this is the first thing we should start with when we are a beginner. Apart from this, there is no difference.